# How to use Visual Studio Resharper shortcut keys(Alt+Enter) to introduce and initialize private fields?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I want to use the VS ReSharper shortcut keys(Alt+Enter) to speed up the initialization of a private fields "_codeInspector" after typing the following code:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class CodingAssistance
    {
        public CodingAssistance(CodeInspector codeInspector)

        public class CodeInspector
        { }
    }
}
```

However, as I pressed Alt+Enter, there was no option called "Introduce and initialize field _codeInspector" as expected.

my situation:
[image]

expected situation:
[image]

As a result, I can not reach the following target by just pressing alt+enter but by manually typing word by word…
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of your `Alt+Enter` popup, the shortcut is probably assigned to Visual Studio's own command (`View.QuickActions`, I believe). What you can do is change Visual Studio settings to display ReSharper's `Alt+Enter` popup and (optionally) have it contain both ReSharper's quick-fixes and context actions and Visual Studio's quick actions and refactorings. You can do one of the following:

1. Go to *Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard*, search for `ReSharper_AltEnter` and assign the `Alt+Enter` shortcut to this command. This should make ReSharper's popup avaialble via `Alt+Enter` and Visual Studio's popup available by its traditional shortcut, `Ctrl+.`.
2. Go to *ReSharper | Options | Code Inspection | Settings* and select *Do not show Visual Studio bulb (VS actions will be merged into ReSharper bulb)*. This should make both ReSharper's and Visual Studio's commands available via ReSharper's popup. This setting can have performance implications, and if you're not comfortable with Visual Studio responsiveness, go with option (1) instead.